# why python shell cannot find MyClass

Tags: python

I have defined c:/temp/t.py as follows:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._my_secret_thing = 1

    def _i_get(self):
        return self._my_secret_thing

    def _i_set(self, value):
        self._my_secret_thing = value

    def _i_delete(self):
        print 'neh!'
        #del self._my_secret_thing

    my_thing = property(_i_get, _i_set, _i_delete,'this document for my_thing')
```

Then I use Python Shell 2.4.4 as follows:

```
>> import sys
>>> sys.path.append('c:/temp')
>>> import t
>>> dir(t)
['MyClass', '__author__', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__']
>>> t = MyClass()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#11>", line 1, in -toplevel-
    t = MyClass()
NameError: name 'MyClass' is not defined
```

**Question**> Why python shell cannot find 'MyClass'?

Comment: Do you mean "c:\temp"?  Windows uses forward slashes.

Comment: `t = MyClass()` Do you realize that this is replacing your module `t` with a variable `t`?  Also.  Why aren't you using `t.MyClass()`?  What tutorial are you using to learn Python?  Can you provide a link or a reference to the tutorial you're using?

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand No. Windows uses normally backslashes (`\\`), but it can handle forward slashes ('/') as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You import a module called `t`.  Because of namespacing, everything defined in `t` has to be accessed through it.

```
import t
inst = t.MyClass()
```

If you want to just get the class and discard everything else in the `t` module, you can do that like so.

```
from t import MyClass
inst = MyClass()
```

Answer (score 4):

You must use `c=t.MyClass()` or `from t import MyClass`. As S.Lott points out you shouldn't mixup variable names and module names.

Answer (score 1):

`t` is module and `MyClass` is one type of attribute for that module. You cant access directly any attribute of the object. You have to include it in your context or you have to access it by that object.

you can access by

```
import t
t.MyClass()
```

or

```
from t import *
MyClass()
```